# How to access returned JSON's values on auto complete selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have this JSON format returned by server by some keyword typed in text box:

```
[{"id":1,"value":"some string!"}]
```

and I want when user selected an item, browser navigate to another page using selection's `id`; which exists in returned JSON. this is my auto complete code:

```
$(function () {

$("#search-box").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../Contenthandler/Search.ashx",
            dataType: "json",
            data: 'query=' + request.term,
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.value };
                })
       );

            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    open: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            window.location.href = "../ControlPanel.aspx?id=" + ui.item.id;
        }
    }
 });

});
```

but `ui.item.id` is `undefined`. How can I access `id`(1) on selection event?

Comment: According to your json result example, the outer most data element is an array.  So you'd need to reference with array notation at that point.

Comment: @Taplar so, How can I access `id`?

Comment: Are you getting a response? In other words, is your `success` handler ever called? @Taplar's point is that the results object *isnt json* but your ajax call is expecting a json response.

Comment: if ui is your base json element it would be ui[0].id, or if item is the base element it would be ui.item[0].id .  console.log() whatever variable your using to see it's structure.

Comment: @Taplar if OP was already getting selections in the UI...why would ajax be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `id` as property of objects you mapped to the array passed to autocomplete within your ajax success.

Your objects only have one property `label`. Add the other properties you need or just extend your response objects with the `label` property

```
 response($.map(data, function (item) {
       return { label: item.value, id : item.id };// add "id" property
  });
```

Actually if the data returned from server is the structure at top of question...you don't need to do any mapping. You really don't need your own ajax either and can wire the server path directly to the plugin.

See demos and docs for setting url path as source